In SwiftUI charts the topmost label on the y axis isn't shown
I am currently trying to implement a swift chart in swift using the Charts framework.
Now if I set the anchor for the AxisValueLabel to any .bottom value, the topmost value isn't shown.

Here is my code so far:
    struct ChartView: View {
    enum ChartType: String, Plottable, CaseIterable {
        case total = "Total"
        case grid = "Grid"
        case solar = "Solar"
        
        var primitivePlottable: String {
            rawValue
        }
    }
    
    struct TestStruct: Identifiable, Hashable {
        var type: ChartType
        var value: Double
        var date: Date
        var id = UUID().uuidString
    }
    
    let testData = [
        TestStruct(type: .total, value: 0, date: Date.now),
        TestStruct(type: .total, value: 21, date: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(60)),
        TestStruct(type: .total, value: 19, date: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(2*60)),
        TestStruct(type: .total, value: 17, date: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(3*60)),
        TestStruct(type: .total, value: 12, date: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(4*60)),
        TestStruct(type: .total, value: 0, date: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(5*60))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
            Chart {
                ForEach(testData) {
                    LineMark(x: .value("Test x", $0.date),
                             y: .value("Test y", $0.value))
                        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", $0.type))
                    
                    AreaMark(x: .value("Test x", $0.date),
                             y: .value("Test y", $0.value))
                        .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                            .blue.opacity(0.8),
                            .blue.opacity(0)
                            ]),
                            startPoint: .top,
                            endPoint: .bottom))
                        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", $0.type))
                }
            }
            .chartLegend(position: .top)
            .chartXAxis(content: {
                AxisMarks { _ in
                }
            })
            .chartYAxis(content: {
                AxisMarks(preset: .inset,position: .leading) { _ in
                    AxisValueLabel(anchor: .bottomLeading) {
                        Text("kW")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
                
                AxisMarks(preset: .inset, position: .trailing) { value in
                    AxisGridLine()
                    let number = value.as(Int.self) ?? 0
                    AxisValueLabel(anchor: .bottomTrailing) {
                        Text("\(number)")
                            .font( .footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .offset(x: 20)
                    }
                    AxisTick(centered: false, length: 20)
                        .offset(x: 20)
                }
            })
            
            .frame(height: 290)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .padding(.bottom, 16)
            .padding(.top, 32)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            }
    }
}

If I use the default AxisLabels the topmost label is shown tho.

Someone experienced the same issue and can help me with this?

Can you show a [mcve], and explain what exactly is not showing? Perhaps add a screenshot showing the desired result.

you could try using chartYVisibleDomain

@workingdogsupportUkraine this only works for scrolling and ios17

you could try using .chartYScale(domain: 0...40), seems to work for me in my tests on ios18 and macCatalyst. Are you targeting ios16 or less?

@workingdogsupportUkraine im currently. targeting iOS 16

the docs say .chartYScale(domain: 0...40) is compatible with iOS 16+.

Ok, I got it working with the .chartYScale. It only wokrs if the upper bound is bigger then the displayed value.Eg: if the values are 0, 5, 10, 15 the upper bound must be bigger then 15 other wise 15 will not show
